# Use reflection to take URL and wrap call to service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, asp.net-mvc-5

Suppose `ServiceCommand1_M : IServiceCommand<Type_N>` are all service methods that accept/deserialize and return/serialize in types that could be serialized/serialized with Web-API. Is there a way to do something like (in pseudo-code)

```
http://MyGreatWebService/EatCommand/Pie

=>

new EatCommand<Pie>();
return EatCommand.Execute();
```

so that it could take the URL input and call the appropriate class ("EatCommand") and concrete type ("Pie")? Is there a way to search in the scope of a namespace to find a *single* class inheriting from a generic with that concrete type, ie the single `IServiceCommand<T>` where `T: Pie`?

Comment: You should be able to parametrize `EatCommand` with any type, or you have fixed set of acceptable types?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy there are a fixed set of acceptable types, though they do not really inherit from any specific class